# associate emacs org-mode single file to multiple files?

Tags: linux, emacs, org-mode

I do most of my note taking into a single large text file in emacs under Linux. I would like to be able to write down small README.project files in this large text file, and point them somewhere where each of these REAMDE.project should be. For example:

```
touch ~/mydaily.txt
touch /tmp/project1/README.p1
touch /tmp/project2/README.p2
```

In `~/mydaily.txt`, I would like to be able to label the README.project files in some way:

```
########################################
# file_pointer_of_some_sorts = /tmp/project1/README.p1
The contents of the README for project1 are here
########################################

Some random comment that is only present in my daily notes.

########################################
# file_pointer_of_some_sorts = /tmp/project2/README.p2
The contents of the README for project2 are here
########################################
```

In this way, everytime I want to change something in the READMEs, I
would only need to do it on my large file with the notes, and the
content on the destination file will change.

Any ideas how can this be done with emacs org-mode or any other tool?

Comment: Great idea! I wish I knew how to do it. Probably there's a way to add some entry to the `PROPERTIES` drawer which will indicate that the sub-tree is suppose to generate some file somewhere. Then, you could parse the whole (big) file, and the needed target files will be generated. Is there a specific reason for using a `.txt` extension?

Comment: `PROPERTIES` drawer... Ok, I'll Google for it and see if it can be done...